# How should I handle a Java POST that can have a RequestBody of multiple types?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, deserialization

So I have a Spring RestController and one of my endpoints is used to perform operations on a generic typed object passed into my RequestBody as so:

```
@PostMapping("/endpoint")
public <T extends Comparable<T>> ResponseEntity<Integer> balancingPost(@RequestBody MyCustomObject<T> mco)
```

So after a lot of searching it doesn't seem this can be done without explicitly stating the type at some point. However as it stands my controller has no way of knowing the type (the program calling the POST does though). So how should I handle this? Is there a way to post my Class of T as well and somehow map it?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
public ResponseEntity<?>  balancingPost(@RequestBody MyCustomObject<T> mco) {
    ResponseEntity<?> response = null;

    try {
        /*Some condition*/
        if (!auth.equals(authCode)) {
            response = new ResponseEntity<>("Unauthorized", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        } else {
            MyModel model = service.getModel();
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(model, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        response = new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```